# response.stream and web2py_component: Not able to stream file as attachment

Tags: ajax, stream, components, response, web2py

I want to stream a file as an attachment in the response. I have this function:

```
def form_query():
    response.flash = str(request.args(0))
    response.generic_patterns = ['load']
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = gluon.contenttype.contenttype('.txt')
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=somefile.txt'
    #more code goes in here to process request.args here. 
    #Ultimately, the controller is expected to return a dict containing a table and the file to be streamed as an attachment. For now just trying to get the file streamed.
    return response.stream(open('somefile.txt'),chunk_size=1024)
```

When I call this controller normally (if I put the streaming code inside index() and go to index.html for e.g.) it responds by opening up a download popup to save the file to disk. But when I have this called as a target function from web2py_component in index.html (to fill a div with the response)like this:

```
web2py_component("{{=URL('reports', 'form_query.load')}}" + "/" + jQuery(this).val(), target='div_form_query');
```

It renders the file inside the DIV 'div_form_query' rather than popup a download window.

Any ideas how to render the file as an attachment while using web2py_component. I'm using web2py_component as I want to conditionally load input forms into that div target (div_form_query) based on a select list which has tables as options. The index.html looks something like:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

{{=SELECT('Select a report', 
*[OPTION(repts[i].descr, _value=str(repts[i].report)) for i in range(len(repts))], _id="rep_type")}}

<div id="div_form_query"></div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#rep_type').change(function(){
     web2py_component("{{=URL('reports', 'form_query.load')}}" + "/" + jQuery(this).val(), target='div_form_query');
    });

    });
</script>
{{end}}
```

Thanks,
mave

Comment: What's the point of the component div if you want the file to be downloaded as an attachment? The div implies you want to display something on the page.

Comment: Anthony, yes exactly the DIV must display a response from the controller in addition to the controller triggering a download.. sorry if it wasn't clear above, I want the controller (form_query) to do two things: return a dict containing a table that goes into the target DIV and trigger a file download. The code above for the form_query() doesnt show the code for returning a dict containing a table.

Comment: You'll need to make two separate calls -- one for the table and one for the file (probably makes sense for those to be two separate functions). See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will do what you want:

```
jQuery('#rep_type').change(function(){
  var choice = jQuery(this).val();
  web2py_component('{{=URL('reports', 'create_table')}}' + '/' + choice,
    target='div_form_query');
  window.open('{{=URL('reports', 'form_query')}}' + '/' + choice);
});
```

Another option would be to only call `web2py_component()` above, and then in the component HTML, include a script that does the following:

```
window.open('{{=URL('reports', 'form_query')}}' + '/' + choice);
```